# Match 2 lists of strings by ressemblance

Tags: algorithm, string, list, matching

**Problem**

I have 2 lists of strings.  I want to find the best matching pairs from my lists.

For example, I have those 2 lists:

```
list1 = {"a1","b1","c1"}
list2 = {"a2","b2","c2"}
```

I want to get the following results:

```
results = {{"a1,"a2"}, {"b1,"b2"}, {"c1,"c2"}}
```

**Additional Info**

To compare 2 strings together, I would like to use something similar to the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).  For example, when I compare `"a1"` with `"a2"`, it gives me a shorter distance than `"a1"` with `"b2"`, so `"a1"`+`"a2"` would be considered a better match.

I gets complicated when different pairs gets the same distance results. You can't just take minimum distance for a specific item in `list1`, because another item in `list1` could obtain the same distance with the same item in `list2`.

**Question**

Do you have suggestions of algorithms for that?

**Where I am right now**

You better not look at my finding first so you don't get influenced by my work.

I calculate the Levenshtein distance for each possible pair of string and store the results in a 2-dimension array.  Then I build a single dimension array where each element has:

- the pair (the i,j indexes in my 2-dimension array)
- the distance

Then I sort this array by using distance element.

Finally, I go through the sorted array and resolve the items with a common distance together (all distance==0 first, then all distance==1, etc...).  Every time, I resolve an element, I mark it in my 2D array, so I can quickly skip the resolved items in my sorted array.

I think I can better than this solution.  It may not the most efficient in time and space.

Comment: Please define best matching. Is it sum of distances? Sum of squares of distances?

Comment: If you want to minimize the sum of distances, your problem seems to be a maximum weighted bipartite matching, if this helps.

Comment: @biziclop very interesting question.  I did not see the problem like this.  I am not sure which one would be the best: sum of distances or sum of squares.  I will investigate those avenues.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have established the metric you want to use to keep track of the "distance" between two strings, be it the Levenshtein distance or another one, you can use the [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) to solve your problem.

I personally have never implement it, but Wikipedia includes several links that might be of help.

Comment: After investigating the comments left by biziclop, I found this algorithm that perfectly match my problem.  thank you!

Comment: Note: the Hungarian Algorithm is working and returning good results, however it shows a severe performance issue.  The algorithm is O(N^3) and when used with hundreds of entries, it can quickly become extremely long to process.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many is "hundreds of entries": 200, 300, ...?

Comment: I found that performance varies a lot depending on the content.  When the matches are easy to do (perfect matches or close matches with low amount of ambiguity) the performance is very good.  But when you pass totally unrelated lists, with just 100 entries, the performance is disastrous (like 30+ seconds).  Hopefully, for me, the normal case is for lists that match well.

Comment: Hmm... O(n^3) with 100 entries taking 30+ seconds. There sure is a pretty large constant hidden in the O-notation.

Comment: I found the performance issues were related to using STL in debug.  The same scenario taking 30 seconds in DEBUG takes less than 100 ms in a Release build.

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to speed the process!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion for a possible optimization to this:

```
I calculate the Levenshtein distance for each possible pair of string and store the results in a 2-dimension array.
```

Is that you can avoid computing the distance for every possible pair of the string by considering their lengths. Because let's say:

```
1. if the pair is e.g. "ab", and "cdefg"
2. and you know that there's another string that has similar length with "ab" e.g. "xy"
```

Then you shouldn't need to calculate the distance between "ab" and "cdefg". Because the minimum distance you can get between strings of those lengths is 3, whereas the maximum distance between two strings of equal lengths ("ab" and "xy" as in the example) will be 2.

You can do this by using a smarter data structure that keeps track of length of strings e.g. `unordered_map<int, vector<string> >` in C++0x or tr1 C++.