# NSCaseInsensitiveSearch does not work

Tags: objective-c, string-comparison, case-insensitive

I tried to compare two strings in a case-insensitive way.

```
NSString *name1 = @"Fridtjof-Nansen-Straße";
NSString *name2 = @"Bergwald Fridtjof-Nansen-Str.";

NSString *name3 = @"Karlsruhe Hirtenweg/Techn.park";
NSString *name4 = @"Hirtenweg/Technologiepark";

NSRange nameRange1 = [name2 rangeOfString:name1 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
NSRange nameRange2 = [name3 rangeOfString:name4 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
if(nameRange1.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"%@ and %@ are similar",name1,name2);
}

if(nameRange2.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"%@ and %@ are similar",name1,name2);
}
```

But regarding to my string examples, the code I used did not work. What can I do instead? You can see the similarity, but I can't find a working way.

Best regards,
Nazar

Comment: I don't understand. What are you trying to do exactly? It seems that you're confused about `rangeOfString:options:`, or `NSCaseInsenstive`. Plus the logs are weird. If `nameRange1.location != NotFound`, it means that somewhere inside `name2`, the `name1` appears. That doesn't mean they are equals.

Comment: I try to compare `name1` with `name2` and `name3` with `name4`. When you look at `name2`,you can see that it contains many characters from `name1` (even in the right order).

Comment: `NSCaseInsensitive`: don't take in account if letters are uppercase or lowercase. If strings are not EXACTLY the same (as a substring), you'll get `NSNotFound` for `rangeOfString:options:`.

Comment: You seems more interested into the Levenshtein distance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587127/match-2-lists-of-strings-by-ressemblance (others questions on SO are present too).

Comment: Thanks Larme, this helped me a lot. There were also other fuzzy string-matching-algorithms like n-gram or jaro-winkler distance, which were pretty good. But in my case the results I got from each of the algorithms aren't enough. What I thought is to use the web for a semantic comparison between the strings. I read something about SparQL which is a query language for crawling web contents.